# The maximum inner vector length in a 2D vector

Tags: c++

Say you have a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` where the `size()` of the inner vectors is variable.

Is there a compact way to get the maximum inner vector `size()`?

Comment: No, there is no magic button to be pressed, somewhere, which makes the answer pop out. This must be done the old fashioned way: a loop, and tracking the maximum inner vector size, checking each vector's size, one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a compact way to get the maximum inner vector `size()`?

This depends on your definition of "compact". Here's the general idea, valid in C++14 and later:

```
#include <algorithm>

// Returns the maximum size() of contained type. Outer container must NOT be empty.
template <typename T>
std::size_t max_inner_size(const T& outer)
{
    auto cmp = [](auto& a, auto& b) { return a.size() < b.size(); };
    return std::max_element(outer.begin(), outer.end(), cmp)->size();
}
```

You could argue this is compact, because now you have a re-usable function template that works on any forward-iterable standard container which holds types that implement a `size()` function returning a value compatible with `std::size_t`.

So, you can then call `max_inner_size`, passing your "outer" container:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> stuff{
        {1, 2, 3}, {}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8}
    };
    std::cout << max_inner_size(stuff);
}
```

The above will output `4`.

If you mean "compact" in terms of a standard library feature that provides a brief one-liner, without you needing to write your own function, then the answer is no. It's entirely *your* choice to have a vector-of-vectors, and the standard library doesn't care.

You could turn the provided function template into a one-liner, but why would you do that? Even if you only need it once, your code is still going to be much cleaner and more concise if you encapsulate that special functionality in a function.